# Optimize PySpark Dataframe aggregation on Column with dict

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to process a DataFrame with the following structure:

| name | countries | options |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dummy1 | ["UK", "FR"] | [{"id": 1, "key1": 10, "key2": 20}, {"id": 2, "key1": 10, "key2": 20}] |
| dummy1 | ["FR"] | [{"id": 1, "key1": 20, "key2": 30}] |
| dummy2 | ["UK", "FR"] | [{"id": 1, "key1": 10, "key2": 20}] |

Into something like this

| name | countries | options |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dummy1 | ["UK", "FR"] | [{"id": 1, "key1": 20, "key2": 30}, {"id": 2, "key1": 10, "key2": 20}] |
| dummy2 | ["UK", "FR"] | [{"id": 1, "key1": 10, "key2": 20}] |

So basically the idea is to group by `name`, get an distinct list of `countries`, and a list of options, where, if the id's are grouped and only the highest `key1` (or `key2` if `key1` is the same) is kept

I am able to solve the issue by aggregating the countries like this

```
countries = df.groupBy(col("name") \ 
              .agg(array_distinct(flatten(collect_list(col("countries")))
```

and joining it the options aggregation

```py
window = Window().partitionBy("name").orderBy(col("key1").desc(), col("key2").desc()) 
options = df.select("name", explode("options").alias("options")) \ 
            .withColumn("id", col("options.id") \ 
            .withColumn("key1", col("options.key1") \ 
            .withColumn("key2", col("options.key2") \ 
            .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(window)) \ 
            .filter("rn = 1") \ 
            .groupBy(col("name")) \ 
            .agg(collect_list(options))
```

However, this is quite slow give the volume of data to process. I would guess that trying to make it in one go, without the join would be faster, but the way I achieved that was also quite slow.

Do you see any optimisations I could do to my code to make it run faster?

Answer (score 0):

In one go: for get unique countries, `collect_set` function with separate Window can be used, and flattened later. On Scala (guess, can be converted to Python easily):

```
   // case class Keys(id: Int, key1: Int, key2: Int)
val df = Seq(
  ("dummy1", Seq("UK", "FR"), Seq(
    Keys(1, 10, 20),
    Keys(2, 10, 20)
  )),
  ("dummy1", Seq("FR"), Seq(
    Keys(1, 20, 30)
  )),
  ("dummy2", Seq("UK", "FR"), Seq(
    Keys(1, 10, 20)
  ))
).toDF("name", "countries", "options")


val nameIdWindow = Window.partitionBy("name", "option.id")
  .orderBy(desc("option.key1"), desc("option.key2"))

val nameWindow = Window.partitionBy("name")

val result = df
  .select(
    $"name",
    collect_set($"countries").over(nameWindow).alias("countries_array_arrays"),
    explode($"options").alias("option")
  )
  .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(nameIdWindow))
  .filter("rn = 1")
  .withColumn("countries", array_distinct(flatten($"countries_array_arrays")))
  .groupBy($"name", $"countries")
  .agg(collect_set("option").alias("options"))
```

Result:

```
+------+---------+--------------------------+
|name  |countries|options                   |
+------+---------+--------------------------+
|dummy1|[FR, UK] |[{1, 20, 30}, {2, 10, 20}]|
|dummy2|[UK, FR] |[{1, 10, 20}]             |
+------+---------+--------------------------+
```